# How to start Linux applications from Windows and vice verse?

Tags: ssh

I get a script that is running on Windows and need to start applications on Linux and another script that is running  on Linux and need to start applications on Windows. The only way that I think up is using ssh through the Cygwin.

May be there is more easy and appropriate solution?

Comment: It seems a little cumbersome and potentially brittle (what happens with temporary DNS failure? Temporary host failures (rebooting)? Or host keys change? Or private keys are compromised?). So I can understand wanting a different mechanism. But what are you trying to accomplish? Why not simply set both programs to run at boot and always be running? :)

Comment: I try to setup testing environment. In our company we have a product that can automatically run services (rmid, orb and others) and we need to test the mechanism. And as you know the best way to test something is using corner-cases a-la Windows-Linux or even better Windows-Solaris:)

Comment: aha, that's an excellent reason. And sounds like an excellent testing strategy, too.